# Can I have an interface that has a live dictionary enabled?

Tags: python, dictionary, live

So basically I want an interface that has some text written. When I hover on individual word, it displays the meaning of the word, sample usecase and pronunciation of the word. I want to do all this while I hover at each word, is that possible? Also I want to use Python for this.

Comment: That sounds like web application. For that you need to use some web framework like Django, Flask, etc in addition to Python. This question is too broad for StackOverflow and most likely will be closed

Comment: Consider using 3rd party APIs -- many dictionary providers provide APIs, some even commercial licenses, so it depends on the scale of your app. I'm not convinced you really need Python here at all. Most of this is frontend work if you use established APIs, so lots of CSS & JS rather than Python. Consider a frontend framework like React or Angular for the frontend. There are plenty of examples online about how to build many of the components you describe. You just need to put it all together. In any case, as mentioned, the question is too broad, so can't really be answered on SO.